# What does a zero area element in the metric mean?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, singularities

Let's consider the metric

$$ds^2= \lambda(r) dt^2 - \lambda^{-1} (r) dr^2 -R(r)^2 d\Omega^2$$

where

$$\lambda(r)= \frac{r+\omega}{r+h}$$

and

$$R(r)^2 = r(r+h)$$

At $r=-h$,  the area element disappears, does this have any physical interpretation?

There is a problem because the temporal part diverges and the radial part goes to zero, but if $\omega=h$, the metric is finite.

This metric was given as an exercise, so it might not be very realistic.

Comment: What are the allowed values for $r$? Is $h$ positive or negative?